# Run JS inside <form action> attribute in input tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to implement a RBAC (based on a users permssions they can only access certain functions). Here I have a menu page with several optiions.

When user clicks on an icon, I would like to check if the user has the necessary permissions by calling the *check_rights.php* . Based on the return value of true and false, i woud then redirect user to appropriate page.

in the event a user does not have permission, i am trying to display a popup ; *myalert()* ; with a message, ideally on the same/current page without any refresh.

I have been trying different variations without any luck. Below is my latest "lame"  attempt.

Any suggestions on how to implement such functionality are welcome.

**check_rights() is a php function 
myalert() is a js function**

```
  <form action="">    

    <input  type="submit" formaction= "javascript:check_rights(maintenance); ? &quot/crm/maintenance/maintenance_menu.php&quot;:&quot;myalert()&quot;"  data-inline ="true" data-iconpos="" data-icon="maintenance" />
    <input  type="submit" formaction="/crm/maintenance/hr_menu.php"  data-inline ="true" data-iconpos="" data-icon="humanresources" />
    <input  type="submit" formaction="/crm/maintenance/inventory_menu.php"  data-inline ="true" data-iconpos="" data-icon="inventory" />
    <input  type="submit" formaction="/crm/maintenance/purchase_menu.php"  data-inline ="true" data-iconpos="" data-icon="purchase" />
    <input  type="submit" formaction="/crm/maintenance/sales_menu.php"  data-inline ="true" data-iconpos="" data-icon="sales" />

</form>
```

Comment: EDIT:  check_rights is a php file ,  myalert() is js function

Comment: i see you have the logic. you just need to code it,what have you tried ?

Comment: tried putting php tags for php function as such  ' <input  type="submit" formaction= "javascript: var a = <?phpcheck_rights("maintenance");?> ? &quot/crm/maintenance/maintenance_menu.php&quot;:&quot;myalert()&quot;"  data-inline ="true" data-iconpos="" data-icon="maintenance" />'

Comment: from what i can tell you need some ajax to test if the user has the necessary permissions

Comment: could u please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax. This means you can make a request to the back-end (php), asking to `check_rights();`, and then get a response. However, what 
you tried with php was quite close. Have a look at this

```
<input type="submit" formaction= "<?php echo (check_rights("maintenance"))? '&quot/crm/maintenance/maintenance_menu.php' :  '&quot;:&quot;myale‌​rt()&quot;' ;?> " data-inline ="true" data-iconpos="" data-icon="maintenance" />'
```

...this assumes check_rights returns a boolean or 0/1.

Comment: '<input type="submit" formaction= "javascript:myalert();" data-inline ="true" data-iconpos="" data-icon="maintenance" />'     i have tried the following to simply bring up the dialogue. this also does not work

Comment: ...what about that? If check_rights returns false, that should happen.

Comment: indeed, i am trying with a user account that returns true and yet the page is not redirected.. i have simplified to see if i can actually invoke some js function from he formaction attribute and move up from there

Comment: ok..i have solved the issue partly;  the ui-dialogue was not loading because the jquery mobile script was intefering with the google/api/jquery scricpt. Now i will try your previous suggestion